# Implement a class from Interface having implemented methods as static (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, static

```
public class MyClass:MyClassBaseClass, IInterface 
{
   public static method A()
   {
   }

   public static method B() 
   { 
   }
}
```

Consider the snippet above.

I want to implement an interface in my class. I want to make all the implemented methods from interface **`IInterface`** as static in my class so that I do not have to create an instance before calling the method. Why I am not allowed to do it and what are the possible solutions and workaround to do the same thing which I wish to do.

Comment: The workaround is the [Singleton Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: @AshwinNair Thanks for quick update. Is there a good way to achieve this  ?

Comment: Nothing using an `Interface` unfortunately. If you must use static methods, create a separate class for them since they'll probably be utility methods or use the singleton pattern as @Peter4499 suggested. He's even included a link :) .